# Get oneOf-prop to change className, CSS modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes, css-modules

This classname takes in an oneOf-prop that is equal to a class (example:'primary'). I'm trying to figure out how to format this classname so that it's working with CSS Modules.

The code below renders the classname as styles.primary if we pass in primary as prop. But we wont get it handled by css-modules. [See this image of rendered classnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2OiL.png)

```
import styles from '../../styles/components/buttons/Cta.module.css'; 
   
export const CTA = ({ fit, type, ...props }) => {
    const mode = fit ? styles.fit : styles.fill;
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className={[styles.cta, `styles.${type}`, mode].join(' ')}
        {...props}
      >
      </button>
    );
  };
  CTA.propTypes = {
    fit: PropTypes.bool,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'disabled']),
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
 <li className={`${css.notification} ${css.important}`}>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use backticks instead of using an array. The main issue is to format the className so that we can get the prop. if we write ${styles.type}, it renders undefined.